# How to access a dict from a PY file in Jinja for Flask Website

Tags: python

Im creating a site on flask, using jinja i want to access a dict from my dict.py file to display a table on my template but I am given a 'coin_dict' is undefined error on when i  render. Any help?

Template Code to access keys and values from dict:

```
 {% for key, value in coin_dict() %}
       <tr>
           <td> {{ key }} </td>
           <td> {{ value }} </td>
       </tr>
       
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a `coin_dict()` dictionary and you're sending it to the template properly (for ex., `render_template('template.html', coin_dict=coin_dict)`), you would want your template `for` statement to look like this:

```html
{% for key, value in coin_dict.items %}
```

To properly iterate through a Python dictionary you must use the `dict.items()` method.